# Is it possible and how to predict individual survival curve after Cox regression?

Tags: survival, cox-model, hazard, kaplan-meier, proportional-hazards

Taking the `veteran` dataset of a two-treatment, randomized trial for lung cancer in the R package `survival` as an example, where

- `time` is the survival time in days
- `status` is the censoring status (0 for surviving and 1 for dead)
- `trt` is the treatment type (1 or 2)
- `celltype`: 1=squamous, 2=small cell, 3=adeno, 4=large
- `age`: age in years

(There are more covariates but for simplicity I only included 3)

Adding in the above covariates/factors, the Cox regression can be run as follows:

```
library(survival)
cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ trt + celltype + age, data = veteran)
summary(cox)

# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ trt + celltype + age, data = veteran)

#   n= 137, number of events= 128 

#                       coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)    
# trt               0.179011  1.196034 0.201404 0.889    0.374    
# celltypesmallcell 1.080310  2.945592 0.274647 3.933 8.37e-05 ***
# celltypeadeno     1.170470  3.223506 0.294727 3.971 7.15e-05 ***
# celltypelarge     0.292624  1.339939 0.285504 1.025    0.305    
# age               0.004097  1.004106 0.009581 0.428    0.669    
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

                  exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
# trt                   1.196     0.8361    0.8059     1.775
# celltypesmallcell     2.946     0.3395    1.7195     5.046
# celltypeadeno         3.224     0.3102    1.8091     5.744
# celltypelarge         1.340     0.7463    0.7657     2.345
# age                   1.004     0.9959    0.9854     1.023

# Concordance= 0.619  (se = 0.028 )
# Likelihood ratio test= 26.04  on 5 df,   p=9e-05
# Wald test            = 25.01  on 5 df,   p=1e-04
# Score (logrank) test = 26.51  on 5 df,   p=7e-05
```

Now, these coefficients allow me to compute the hazard ratio between any two groups of patients, each with a set of `trt`, `celltype`, and `age`. For examples, if

- group A has `trt` = 1, `celltype` = squamous, and age = 49, and
- group B has `trt` = 2, `celltype` = smallcell, and age = 50,

then we can say that at any time point, the proportion of subjects from group B who have died from group B should be $1.196\times2.946\times1.004=3.538$ times of that from group A. But this does not allow us to tell the proportion of survival at any time point for either group A or B - we only know the ratio.

In broader term, is it possible to tell at any given time point, for a group of patients with known `trt`, `celltype`, and `age`, the proportion of survival? If all terms tested are factors, we can just subset the target population from the dataset and generate the Kaplan-Meier curve, but then `age` is present in the model. Maybe a relevant question is: what is the baseline hazard function $h_0(t)$ in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The baseline hazard rate $h_0(t)$ is hard to estimate (takes smoothing), but the baseline cumulative hazard $H_0(t)$ is easy.  Given $H_0(t)$ you can estimate an individual survival curve by
$$\log S(t;z) = H(t;z) = H_0(t)e^{\beta z}$$

Basically any survival analysis software will both let you get individual survival estimates and also compute the Breslow-Aalen estimator of $H_0$
$$\hat{H}_0(t)=\int_0^t\frac{dN(s)}{\sum_i e^{\beta z_i}Y_i(s)}$$
This is like the Nelson-Aalen estimator of the cumulative hazard for a group, except that the denominator is not the number at risk but a weighted number at risk using the individual hazard ratios as weights.

You do need to check whether your specific software defines $H_0(t)$ as the cumulative hazard when all covariates are zero or (more conveniently) as the cumulative hazard when all covariates are equal to the baseline averages. In R, you want `predict.coxph`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. So it looks like individual $\hat{H}(t; z)$ is based on the non-parametric device, $\hat{H}_0(t)$, as well as the results from Cox regression $e^{\sum \beta z}$.

Comment: That's right.  The baseline hazard isn't needed to estimate $\beta$ but it is needed to estimate survival curves.